# How can you attach WinDbg to a process running inside a Windows Docker Container?

Tags: docker, windbg, docker-for-windows, .net-framework-version

How can I attach WinDbg to a process running inside a Windows Docker Container?
I've tried googling it, but everything seems to use Visual Studio to do this. I just want to use WinDbg or something similar to quickly analyse a process running on the host.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Typing "windbg docker" in a search engine (please refine for your particular situation) gives plenty of results some of which are from the Microsoft official site. What is the problem you get when following those recommendations and in which way aren't they adapted to your specific situation ?

Comment: @Zeitounator Maybe you should actually read some of those links (like I have already) as you will see that they use visual-studio and in fact not windbg. I don't know if you've ever tried remote debugging using visual studio. If you have then you know why I use windbg. If you don't have experience with this, then feel free to let someone else comment.

Comment: Forget the specific links if they are not relevant. The fact is: there is information out there on how to setup windbg (in a docker container or not). And you will get a much better chance to get an answer if you actually describe and show what you have tried already, or even just list the links you have read and how they do not fit with your situation. My comment was more or less a rephrase of some [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) (and related help articles) tips even though (you are totally right) I know absolutely nothing about the subject. But you are absolutely free to ignore it.

Comment: @Zeitounator I appreciate your comments but, I feel you are penalising me for not using some information that you suggest exists but haven't actually provided a link to. WinDbg is a windows GUI app, I'm pretty sure docker for windows doesn't have a desktop.

Comment: @Zeitounator in fact if you google "windbg docker" the first hit is this question. And the rest of the hits are completely irrelevant.

Comment: I've simplified the question

Comment: That actually looks better IMO. Meanwhile, I really wonder why you think I'm penalizing you when I only tried to help. If you are referring to votes, you should definitely 1) decouple votes and comments (as an example, I usually don't comment when I downvote and vice-versa, and I am not the downvoter here) 2) not pay that much attention to downvotes except as an indication that your question should probably be enhanced (and you might have people reconsider their votes after you do so....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Docker For First Time so maybe this is not what you are looking for
I don't do c# asp.net iis  thingies for which Docker Seems to be Famous for

so here goes
installed Docker Desktop

```
C:\>docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:14:16 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8891c58
  Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:26:48 2020
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

skimmed through get-started

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

pulled Microsoft/nanoserver:1803

```
C:\>docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
microsoft/nanoserver   1803      65194053090c   11 months ago   378MB
```

run the container in background detached interactive with a name

```
C:\>docker run -d -it --name="mydoc" microsoft/nanoserver:1803
23b9265196659cc073bc05ec81f6b58be465db6e305645e1af13c5831c0ca4e3
```

stop it

```
C:\>docker stop mydoc
mydoc
```

copy the windbg x64 folder and a /MT compiled console c++ printf app for test

```
C:\>docker cp d:\doc_trans\ mydoc:c:\
```

start the container

```
C:\>docker start mydoc
mydoc
```

execute cdb on the app

```
C:\>docker exec -it mydoc "c:\\doc_trans\\x64\\cdb.exe" c:\\doc_trans\printf.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: c:\\doc_trans\printf.exe
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is:
ModLoad: 00007ff7`76420000 00007ff7`76487000   printf.exe
ModLoad: 00007ff8`86e60000 00007ff8`87041000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`84290000 00007ff8`84503000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`83b20000 00007ff8`83b45000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\forwarders\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`83fd0000 00007ff8`84017000   C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll
(660.664): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll -
ntdll!LdrInitShimEngineDynamic+0x34c:
00007ff8`86f2c8bc cc              int     3
0:000> g 00007ff7`76420000+1000
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for printf.exe
printf+0x1000:
00007ff7`76421000 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
0:000> uf .
printf+0x1000:
00007ff7`76421000 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
00007ff7`76421004 488d0d35c30400  lea     rcx,[printf+0x4d340 (00007ff7`7646d340)]
00007ff7`7642100b e870000000      call    printf+0x1080 (00007ff7`76421080)
00007ff7`76421010 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00007ff7`76421012 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
00007ff7`76421016 c3              ret
0:000> t
printf+0x1004:
00007ff7`76421004 488d0d35c30400  lea     rcx,[printf+0x4d340 (00007ff7`7646d340)]
0:000> t
printf+0x100b:
00007ff7`7642100b e870000000      call    printf+0x1080 (00007ff7`76421080)
0:000> da @rcx
00007ff7`7646d340  "hello jmp far."
0:000>
```